# Randomly Assign Observations into either Test or Control for a SAS dataset

Tags: sas

I have a large SAS dataset and I want to randomly assign the observations to different test and control groups.

20% of observations would have be Control
5% would be Test1
75% would be Test2

Basicaly,

```
obs
1
2
3
4
5
```

would become

```
obs cell
1   control
2   test2
3   test2
4   test1
5   test2
```

How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROC SURVEYSELECT` is the base way of doing this.  However, Surveyselect doesn't allow picking 3 groups at once.

You can either do this in the data step, or use SURVEYSELECT twice; once to pick the first group (20%), then pick the second group (75%/80%, 93.75%) from the unselected, then still-unselected are group 3.

In the datastep this isn't terribly difficult; you can either just assign a random value, sort the data by the random value, then take first 5% of records as 1, next 20% of (all) records as 2, and last 75% as 3; or you can use k/n sampling with some modifications for a third group.